# Force rows onto a new column in HTML (or javascript?) by setting a max of 5 rows per column

Tags: html-table

On our website, we have a table with 5 rows and 3 columns.

https://www.bakashana.org/sponsor-a-young-woman

The table is in HTML. The problem is that when we get a new girl to sponsor, we put her at the beginning (top left of the table, the first column and row).  This means I have to take the last row entry (picture) from each column and move it down to be the first row entry in the next column.  This is a big hassle and takes lots of time.

I am looking for an easy solution which will allow me to simply add another girl's picture (row) at the *beginning* of the table, and have the table automatically force the rest of the rows to adjust (keeping only 5 rows in each column, and creating a new column if necessary to accommodate all the rows).

Thanks!

Site Code:

```html
<table class="girlstable" style="background:transparent; vertical-align:top;">
<tr style="background:transparent;">
<td>[caption id="attachment_6483" align="aligncenter" width="100"]<a href="#Christine Mupeseni"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/highcompress-Christine-thumbnail-150x150.jpg" alt="christine zambia scholarship kasama" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-6483" /></a> Christine Mupeseni[/caption]</td><td>[caption id="attachment_6495" align="aligncenter" width="100"]<a href="#Joan Chonto"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Joan-Chonto-Headshot-compressor.jpg" alt="Kasama sponsorship zambia" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-full wp-image-6495" /></a> Joan Chonto[/caption]</td><td>[caption id="attachment_6490" align="aligncenter" width="100"]<a href="#Catherine Mwansa"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Catherine-Mwansa-headshot-compressor.jpg" alt="Sponsor young Zambian woman Catherine" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-full wp-image-6490" /></a> Catherine Mwansa[/caption]</td><td>[caption id="attachment_6486" align="aligncenter" width="100"]<a href="#Elizabeth Muma"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/highcompress-elizabeth-muma-thumbnail-150x150.jpg" alt="Elizabeth scholarship kasama" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-6486" /></a> Elizabeth Muma[/caption]
</td><td>[caption id="attachment_6498" align="aligncenter" width="100"]<a href="#Catherine Chipanta"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Catherine-Chipanta-headshot-compressor.jpg" alt="girl child assistance catherine" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-full wp-image-6498" /></a> Catherine Chipanta[/caption]</td></tr>
<tr style="background:transparent;"><td>[caption id="attachment_3836" align="aligncenter" width="100%"]<a href="#Priscilla Mulenga"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Priscilla-Mulenga-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-3836" /></a> Priscilla Mulenga[/caption]</td><td>[caption id="attachment_3837" align="aligncenter" width="100%"]<a href="#Sara Kanyanta"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Sara-Kanyantag-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-3837" /></a> Sara Kanyanta[/caption]</td><td>[caption id="attachment_3702" align="aligncenter" width="100%"]<a href="#Kasonde Marvel"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Kasonde-Marvel-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-3702" /></a> Kasonde Marvel[/caption]</td><td>[caption id="attachment_4900" align="aligncenter" width="100%"]<a href="#Jane Kampamba"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Jane-Kampamba.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-full wp-image-4900" /></a> Jane Kampamba[/caption]</td><td>[caption id="attachment_4899" align="aligncenter" width="100%"]<a href="#Lastage Musonda"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/lastage.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-full wp-image-4899" /></a> Lastage Musonda[/caption]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>[caption id="attachment_3731" align="aligncenter" width="100%"]<a href="#Constance Mulenga"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Costance-Mulenga-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-3731" /></a> Constance Mulenga[/caption]</td><td>[caption id="attachment_3835" align="aligncenter" width="100%"]<a href="#Vanessa Kapembwa"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Vanessa-Kapembwa-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-3835" /></a> Vanessa Kapembwa[/caption]</td><td>[caption id="attachment_3704" align="aligncenter" width="100%"]<a href="#Violet Chilufya"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Violet-Chilufya-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-3704" /></a> Violet Chilufya[/caption]</td><td>[caption id="attachment_3800" align="aligncenter" width="100%"]<a href="#Joyce Chileshe"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Joyce-Chileshe-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-3800" /></a> Joyce Chileshe[/caption]</td><td>[caption id="attachment_3845" align="aligncenter" width="100%"]<a href="#Regina Chokwe"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Regina-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-3845" /></a> Regina Chokwe[/caption]</td>


</tr></table><hr />
```

Comment: are you moving the pictures by hand?

Comment: No, moving the last td from the first tr, making it the first td in the second tr, and continuing that throughout the whole table

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: sure, thanks for you help.  I have edited the post to include the code of the table, which i wish to limit to 5 rows somehow so that when I add a new picture, the rest push themselves down on the table

Comment: Are you using any sort of programming language to make your site dynamic? or is this just plain html?

Comment: just html, css, and media queries

Comment: I would suggest you get started with back-end programming. What that means is you generate HTML dynamicly and would open many doors for you. For a starter i would choose PHP but there are many options like node.js, ASP .NET core, Flask and many more. [this article might help you](https://learntocodewith.me/posts/backend-development/).